# How to import css from node module in Reagent

Tags: css, clojurescript, reagent

I just tried to create a project in clojurescript, that uses react-table.
I import react-table like that

`(:require [react-table :as rt :default ReactTable])`

Obviously, this isn't imported CSS from react-table.

In javascript+React it would be 
`import "react-table/react-table.css"`

**Question:**
What I should do in the clojurescript? 
For now, I just copied CSS from react-table to my css folder and link it in my index.html

Answer (score 4):

As I using **shadow-cljs** to compile clojerescript, after a little googling I realized

1. **shadow-cljs** does nothing about packing css and you [should use something else](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs/issues/353)
2. one variant of 'something else' [modular-styles](https://github.com/ghivert/modular-styles)
3. for **react-table** I will end up with custom styles anyway, so the current "solution" is good enough.

P.S. I'll try to configure [modular-styles](https://github.com/ghivert/modular-styles) in my project, and then I'll update this answer.

Comment: Did you succeed in configuring your project?

Comment: For now, I switched to the [Material-UI](https://material-ui.com/) which uses [JSS](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.3) for styling